# Moving the image to right in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to web development, I have a code like this :

```
<style type="text/css">
    span {
        background:red;
        background: transparent url(../images/skin/exception.png) 0.4em 100% no-repeat;
    }
</style>
 <span>
    Contents. 
 </span>
```

I get the output but the image is been placed over `Contents` text. I tried with :

```
 background-position: 25px;
```

But that is making the image to disappear! But what I was looking for is :

`Contents .  . . . . . . . . . . . .                           my_image`

(note that `.` in above is space)

Where I'm making the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `background-position: center right;`

Comment: A `<span>` doesn't span a block. Add `display:block`.

Comment: I don't get it... Why are you using a background image instead of a simple `image` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `<span>` is an inline element, which is not the correct markup to use for items that you wish to display in a block manner. For that, you should use a `<div>`. That being said, you can use `text-indent: 25px;` to move your text to the right. Alternatively, you can move the new `<div>` to the right using `left: 25px;`. Remember that `left` will tell it how far from the left border you wish to place it. Then, you can place the text in another `<div>`:

```
<style type="text/css">
div {
    display:inline-block;
}
div.image {
    background:red;
    background:transparent url(../images/skin/exception.png) 0.4em 100% no-repeat;
    left:25px;
}
</style>
<div class="box">
  Contents.
  <div class="image"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like (from his original code) that he wants to incorporate the background image into the display of the error (notice background color of red and transparency).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need that your image is a `background-image` you can apply this:

**CSS:**

```
<style>

div#box{
    width: 100%;
}

img#image {
    float: right;
}

</style>
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="box">
    <span id="content">
        Contents.
    </span>
    <img src="bkg.jpg" alt="Image not available">
</div>
```

Comment: The image doesn't need to be in a div - you can just add the id to the `img` tag to get the same effect.

Comment: Yes i know... I can also use a span for the content instead of a `div` so i don't need the `display:inline` property. That was just an example to know if it's a good solution for the poster

Answer (score 0):

I am also agree with @L0j1k that span is a inline level element. Why you are placing some content inside a span and then applying a background image in that span. Anyways please check the jsfiddle link

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/saorabhkr/BvMyg/

Answer (score 0):

Inline:-

```
<span>
//content
<img src="images/skin/exception.png" style="float:right">
</span>
```